# WooCommerce-Send Custom Selected Price in Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello Everyone I have customized the woo-commerce single product page according to my requirement, So now two prices are coming first price is my custom price as per my selection, Second price i have entered from WooCommerce product page(entered from wp-admin dashboard), right now second price is going in cart but i want to pass custom price how can i achieve this please suggest me thank you in advance.

```
Using ajax I am changing my custom price 
 Custom Price:
 <p class="prices" id="demo" style="margin-left:22%;"></p>

Default Price:
<p class="prices"  id="demo" style="margin-left:22%;"><?php  echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

Update:
  I am using this code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price'); 
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {


  $custom_price = 70; // This will be your custome price 
  foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
      $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
  }
```

}

right now 70 is static price instead of this i want to pass paragraph because I am getting my price in paragraph using ajax..

```
  <p class="prices" id="demo" style="margin-left:22%;"></p>
```

[image: woocommerce custom selected price]

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_custom', 10, 2);
function change_price_custom($price, $productd){
    return $price*2; // do calculation here
}
```

Try this in theme's function.php

Comment: your function is calculating for default price i want to pass custom price in cart i am using ajax for calculation through ajax i am calling php file in that i have written query how can i do this please suggest...

Comment: please check my updated code in paragraph  i am getting my price now i want to pass in paragraph but it is not working help me man..

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_price_html', 100, 2 );
function my_price_html( $price, $product ){
    return '<div class="custom-price"> ur Price</div>';
}  // hook on get price html